# Is it required to do unbind() or off() before calling html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, memory-leaks

Is it required to execute `jQuery` `unbind()` or `off()` functions for html elements before calling `jQuery` `html()` to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: @Florent Absolutely not...

Comment: So, `jQuery` is smart :)

Comment: Correction: The people who *wrote* jQuery are smart ;)

Comment: Yes, jQuery is smart :) jQuery takes care of removing any event or data associated to the content elements of you container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not required.

The `html` function takes care of cleaning everything before to set the `innerHTML`.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) :

> Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.

---

Implementation details :

The `html` function calls `empty` whose code is here :

```
empty: function() {
    var elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
        }

        // Remove any remaining nodes
        while ( elem.firstChild ) {
            elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
        }

        // If this is a select, ensure that it displays empty (#12336)
        // Support: IE<9
        if ( elem.options && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "select" ) ) {
            elem.options.length = 0;
        }
    }

    return this;
},
```